# to find if list have the negative sign

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function. In that function I am passing a list.

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
```

Now I wanted to write 2 conditions of l is passed or of -l is passed. -l means negation of all vales in list.
For example

```
-l = [ -1, -2, -3]
```

so, in function either l or -l will be passed as argument.

```
fun test(l):
    Condition1:
        # do if list is negative
    Condition 2:
        # do if list isbpositive
```

how I will check negative sign given to the list in the parameter of a function? Or what are the ways to solve this?

Comment: There is with keyword args but how I can implement in this case?

Comment: mmm... I don't know numpy, but you may have to compare with the original list

Answer (score 1):

well, afaik as i know, there is no unary minus operator on a list - you'd have to create that yourself.

that said... is the invariant that all elements in `l` are either positive or negative? If so, it would be sufficient to check the first entry:

```
def test(l):
    if l[0] > 0:
        # Do if list is positive
    else:
        # Do if list is negative
```

This doesn't seem like a well-specified problem though.. what do you do with a 0 in the list for instance? Is that legal?

And if you allow mixed, then I have no way to know whether `[-1, 2, -3]` is the original list, or someone inverted `[1, -2, 3]`, as the result is the same - in that case, the positive/negative test is meaningless.

If you implement your own unary minus operator though, in your own list-like object, you could track it yourself.

Comment: numpy... well, that makes most of what i said not necessarily applicable, but since it got upvoted must be something useful there...

Comment: `np.negative([1,2,3])` produces `array([-1, -2, -3])`, as does -`array([1,2,3])`.  Not that this helps the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, since when you are calling

```
test(-l)
```

`-l` is evaluated, and then passed to the function. Instead, you could try something like this:

```
def test(l, negative = False):
    if (negative == True):
        l = -l
        ...
    else:            
        ...
```

and call it as:

```
test(l, True) # to pass it as negative
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I may be misinterpreting the question, you could use something like this;

```python
>>> def is_neg(l):
...    # ascertain the sign of the values
...    l = map(lambda value: value < 0, l)
...    # ascertain that all values are negative
...    return all(l)
>>>
>>> l = [-1, -2, -3]
>>> print(is_neg(l))
True
>>> l = [-1, 2, -3]
>>> print(is_neg(l))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can make use of global scope. The problem is that, in this example, you should not already has `-a` in your global scope (say, a `minus_a` defined by `minus_a=-a`).

But if you already have a `minus_a`, you would pass `minus_a` to your `test()` rather than `test(-a)` right?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def test_sign(A):
    q=globals()
    q_arrays=[q[item] for item in q if isinstance(q[item], np.ndarray)]
    result=False
    for item in q_arrays:
        if np.all(item==-A):
            result=True
            break
    return result
>>> a=np.arange(10)
>>> test_sign(a)
False
>>> test_sign(-a)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

In this IPython sequence, I define a custom negating function that sets a flag.  The flag is optionally passed to `test` by means of the `*` and default value.

```
In [47]: ll = np.array([1,2,3])
In [61]: def makeneg(ll):
   ....:     return -ll,True
   ....: 

In [62]: makeneg(ll)
Out[62]: (array([-1, -2, -3]), True)

In [66]: def test(ll, flag=False):
    if flag:
        print ll, 'is negated'
    else:
        print ll,'is not negated'
   ....:         

In [67]: test(ll)
[1 2 3] is not negated

In [68]: test(*makeneg(ll))
[-1 -2 -3] is negated
```